# Create more than one details section using report builder in delphi

Tags: delphi, reportbuilder

I am creating report using metaphor report builder. i need to add more than one detail section. i tried in many ways but still could't make it. it can be designing it from the code. But it can't be possible because when detail section comes more then it is going to the next page. i have attached a image which is what i want to create and that will help to understand the problem. As the image there are four details section that have to have. each of that have medication name which can have more than one medication.hope you can understand my problem. sorry for the bad english.[image]

Comment: Create a subreport for each additional detail section, and modify the detail section within each subreport and callapse the head and footer within the additional subreports.